# Why can I assign doubles sometimes without value?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I wrote a small WF program which caculates some condensators and the ohmic law.  I now want to tidy up a little bit. I ran across a issue where I use 2 doubles which both got assigned the value 0. I can remove the value from the voltage double. But not the current one. And I can't figure out why. Is there anything I am missing? Error Message is CS0165 Use of unassigned local variable 'current' and occurs in the line where the CalcResistance Method gets called

```
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Kondensator_Ohmsches_Gesetz_Calc
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {       
          
        }

        private void calcResistance_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double voltage;
            double current;
            bool ok = double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out voltage) && double.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out current);
            if (ok)
            {
                textBox3.Text = Formulacollection.CalcResistance(voltage, current);
            }
            else
            {
                textBox3.Text = "Error Format not found";
            }
            textBox4.Text = Formulacollection.ConvertMicro(textBox3.Text);
            textBox5.Text = Formulacollection.ConvertMilli(textBox3.Text);
            textBox6.Text = Formulacollection.ConvertKilo(textBox3.Text);
            textBox7.Text = Formulacollection.ConvertMega(textBox3.Text);

        }
}
```

Formulacollection Class works like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using static System.Math;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Kondensator_Ohmsches_Gesetz_Calc
{
    public static class Formulacollection
    {
        public static string CalcResistance(double voltage, double current)
        {
            var resistance = voltage / current;

            return resistance.ToString();
        }
}
```

Comment: it seems the compiler can't properly handle that you store the results of two `TryParse` in a single variable. don't know if this is a bug or by choice. oddly enough, it works if you inline the `ok`-variable - it also works if you separate the check into two booleans and compare call `&&` on _them_ in your if-condition

Comment: This seems very odd. Thanks for the workaround/fix @FranzGleichmann

Comment: Why do you have `string CalcResistance(double voltage, double current)` rather than `double CalcResistance(double voltage, double current)`?

Comment: @Enigmativity  I store this string in the textbox3.Text and it only accepts a string

Comment: @Bododerelf - Then do the `.ToString()` at the time of assignment. You're mixing computations and display otherwise, which is generally bad.

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks for the advice. i will change it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second part won't always be evaluated when you use the && operator. Try to use & instead of it, or set a default value to current when you declare it.

Comment: while that seems to work as well, it's odd that the compiler doesn't have any problem when the original expression, with `&&`, is called directly inside the if-condition

Comment: But why does it call out the parameter when I call the CalcResistance Method? Shouldn't it underline me the current call in the try parse?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly CS0165 is the error occurs when using the uninitialized variable.
But here the error occurs for the variable `current` which is initialized correctly. The brief about the error is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0165)

So try the variable initialization globally in the class and then try to compile it.

Then there is a probability `of` the ok variable holding the value of two `TryParse` simultaneously, and also replace the `&&` with `&`.